# Are there types of Cookies that do not get sent with XHR request?

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest, server-side

I am interested in knowing if I can `set-cookie` and have it not get sent automatically with XHR requests.

> I am not looking for `xhr.withcredentials` answers, I want it all through server side.

**If there is not a way with cookies - is there ANY OTHER WAY to know that a request made to the server was from XHR ? and not through jquery with-xhr flag...**

Comment: Why not use localStorage or sessionStorage in order to perform your operation. They are defined for only this reason.

Comment: @dev_khan — Presumably the cookies are desired on the server when a non-XHR HTTP request is made. Also, the question says "I want it all through server side" so a *purely* client-side option wouldn't work.

Comment: Could you please add more detail to that question? What have you tried so far? Provide code examples and possible error messages. If you need help on how to ask questions please take a look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

No, there aren't.

Depending on how your site is structured, you might be able to prevent the cookie from being sent to the URLs that you access with XHR by using the [`Domain` and/or `Path` directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Scope_of_cookies).

Comment: OK, so not through cookies - but are there any other ways to know that a request made to the server was from XHR ? and not through jquery with-xhr flag...

Comment: No, there isn't. (It sounds increasingly like you have an XY problem. What problem will knowing if a request came from XHR solve?)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use localStorage or sessionStorage in order to perform your operation. They are defined only for this reason.

1. localStorage will retain data even when browser is closed and won't send any data to server.
2. sessionStorage will save data and deletes when user closes the browser and won't send any data to server.

Comment: Presumably the cookies are desired on the server when a non-XHR HTTP request is made. Also, the question says "I want it all through server side" so a *purely* client-side option wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah missed the last sentence.

Comment: but I can't control the localStorage from the set-cookie parameter right ?

Comment: Kindly provide the reason before down voting.

Answer (score 0):

> I am interested in knowing if I can set-cookie and have it not get sent automatically with XHR requests.

On certain browsers you could add the `Secure` directive:

`Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; Secure`

That kind of cookie wouldn't be sent from a non-HTTPS page. Beware though, recent browsers, like [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=976073) and [Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4506322921848832), disabled the addition of *secure* cookies originating from insecure pages.